# Why are my DALL-E Images Coming Out So Desaturated After Resizing?

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, tensor

I'm very new to ML image manipulation/creation, so if I confuse you all with my own lack of knowledge on the subject, I apologize in advance.

I'm attempting to increase the resolution of images produced by DALL-E, inspired by this article:
https://towardsdatascience.com/big-art-using-machine-learning-to-create-high-res-fine-art-7dd695f99788

However, when I attempt to feed images from DALL-E into the "Generate 1K Image" section of the original author's code/colab, my original image becomes very washed out; likely because in the source, some sort of tensor from a different model is fed in, while in my own version, I'm converting an image to a (poorly made?) tensor in the same section and then feeding that in.

Here's what I have:

```
#@title Generate 1K Image
from google.colab import files
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from torchvision import transforms as T
import IPython
import os.path
import cv2
uploaded = files.upload()
texture_amount = 0.05 #@param {type:"slider", min:0, max:0.15, step:0.001}
texture_size = 3 #@param {type:"slider", min:1, max:9, step:2}
enhance_details = True #@param {type:"boolean"}
img = Image.open(BytesIO(uploaded['knight.png']))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor()
])
tensorImage = transform(img)
selected_img = tensorImage.cuda()
selected_img = selected_img.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)
selected_img = selected_img.add(1).div(2)[None, :]

with torch.no_grad():
  torch.cuda.empty_cache()
  resized = bsrgan_model(selected_img)
  torch.cuda.empty_cache()

noise = torch.normal(0, texture_amount, 
  size=[resized.shape[0], 1, resized.shape[2], resized.shape[3]]).to(device)
noise = noise.repeat(1, 3, 1, 1)

noise_blurred = T.GaussianBlur(kernel_size=texture_size, sigma=1)(noise)
noise_blurred = noise*0.25 + noise_blurred*0.75

resized = (resized+noise_blurred)
final_image = resized.to(device)

if enhance_details:
  with torch.no_grad():
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    z, *_ = vqgan_model.encode(final_image * 2 - 1)
    final_image = vqgan_model.decode(z)[0].add(1).div(2).clamp(min=0, max=1)
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    final_image = final_image.clamp(min=0, max=1)
else:
    final_image = final_image[0].clamp(min=0, max=1)

img = T.ToPILImage()(final_image)
img.save("output_1k.png")
IPython.display.Image("output_1k.png")
```

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeSyH.png)
[Resulting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InMfI.png)

Any ideas as to  how I can fix this issue is greatly, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

You are calculating average with 1 for every pixel values in this line.

```py
selected_img = selected_img.add(1).div(2)[None, :]
```

You should change it to this line

```py
selected_img = selected_img[None, :]
```

#### Explanation

(For a pixel if `R G B = 1 1 1`, the color of the pixel is white, and if `R G B = 0 0 0` the color of the pixel is black.) For example if for a pixel these values are `R G B = 0 .5 1`, in the line below, you're changing it to `R G B = .5 .75 1`(getting average with 1). You can check it with this code.

```py
import torch
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from torchvision import transforms

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, constrained_layout=True)

img = Image.open('knight.png')
axs[0].imshow(img)
axs[0].set_title('Original Image')

transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor()
])
tensorImage = transform(img)
selected_img = tensorImage
selected_img = selected_img.type(torch.FloatTensor)

selected_img_0 = selected_img.add(1).div(2)[None, :]
axs[1].imshow(np.squeeze(selected_img_0).permute(1, 2, 0))
axs[1].set_title('Averaged Tensor Image')

selected_img_1 = selected_img[None, :]
axs[2].imshow(np.squeeze(selected_img_1).permute(1, 2, 0))
axs[2].set_title('Tensor Image')

plt.show()
```